# Sort results by “is item in array”

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data set which includes within each document an array of user IDs that have marked the document as a "preferred" one. I want to be able to sort my documents such that these preferred documents are shown first, before the other documents.

So, how can I sort a set of results by "array contains X", where X is a given user ID? I still want to include all results, but sort the ones containing a matching user ID to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`script_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) function which lets you modify the ranking based on a custom script. Your custom script can boost documents which are associated with the current user. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html